# Can Airflow Macros be used with the CloudSqlInstanceExportOperator?

Tags: airflow

We're using Airflow to schedule daily database exports using the [CloudSqlInstanceExportOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/gcp_sql_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.gcp_sql_operator.CloudSqlInstanceExportOperator). This doesn't appear to work with Airflow Macros. We are trying to export 1 day of data using the execution date macro or `{{ ds }}` in the where clause. It's important to use the macro because we want our DAG to backfill.

The sample code is made of of two parts. First we define the [export context](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/operations#ExportContext):

```
    export_body = {
        "exportContext": {
            "fileType": "csv",
             "uri": "gs://"+GCP_BUCKET+'/'data.csv',
             "databases":["database"],
             "csvExportOptions": {
                 "selectQuery": """
                                select * from table 
                                where datetime BETWEEN "{{ ds }} 00:00:00" 
                                AND "{{ ds }} 23:59:59
                                """
             }
        }
    }
```

Next, pass the export context to the task:

```
    cloudsql_export_task = CloudSqlInstanceExportOperator(
            project_id=PROJECT_ID,
            body = export_body,
            instance='instance',
            task_id='cloudsql_export_task',
            dag=dag)
```

The task runs and get's marked as a success, however, the Google Cloud Storage file created has no data in it. When we hard code the date, the query works as expected. As a result, we know the problem is being caused by the macro value not being populated.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Either how to fix this task or an alternative way to achieve the same objective (note: query is large and uses too much memory for MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator to work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the operator includes `body` in `template_fields`.

> You can also use Jinja templating with nested fields, as long as these
> nested fields are marked as templated in the structure they belong to:
> fields registered in `template_fields` property will be submitted to
> template substitution

More info about templating: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/concepts.html#jinja-templating

You can extend the operator like the following

```
class CloudSqlInstanceExportTemplatedOperator(CloudSqlInstanceExportOperator):
    template_fields = CloudSqlInstanceExportOperator.template_fields + ('body',)
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I add that code to extend the operator into the DAG file?

Comment: Answering above question: Yes. But you also need to update the task to use the next extended operator.

Answer (score 1):

shankshera answer is correct however you are using deprecated operator. In the updated version there is no need for the suggested modification.

The `CloudSqlInstanceExportOperator` was renamed to `CloudSQLExportInstanceOperator` and moved to providers.

For **Airflow <2.0** you will need to install [backport providers](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-google/) :

```
pip install apache-airflow-backport-providers-google
```

For **Airflow >=2.0** you will need to install [providers](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-google/):

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-google
```

The you can import the operator as:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.cloud_sql import CloudSQLExportInstanceOperator
```

Since the operator already has `body` listed in the [templated fields](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/bcf77586eff9907fa057cf2633115d5ab3e4142b/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/cloud_sql.py#L867) you are good to go.

Comment: This solution looks best, but we're getting the error:`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.mysql'`. We're on Airflow 1.10.10 and installed the apache-airflow-backport-providers-google package in the virtual env.

Comment: @Srule Note about the section in pypi related to cross dependencies: "Cross provider package dependencies". So you might need also to add `pip install apache-airflow-backport-providers-google[mysql]` depends if you installed all dependencies or picked some manualy.